# htaccess www -> non-www redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect, no-www

Good morning, everyone!
I am trying to use htaccess in my Wordpress site hosted through AWS to redirect http -> https, and www. -> non-www., like so: http://www.example.com to https://example.com.

Currently, the http to https redirect is working as intended. However, "www." is not being stripped from my urls, i.e http://www.example.com becomes https://www.example.com

Note: I for other redirects, I use the Redirection plugin. Furthermore I use Really Simple SSL plugin for https.

I have tried multiple variations of the redirect code, clearing my cache, checking it with incognito, etc.

Here is the current code I am using:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this way:

```
###START MOD_REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

#REDIRECT ALL www REQUESTS OF YOUR SITE TO THE non-www VERSION AND http -> https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(\.dev|staging)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
###END MOD_REWRITE

###BEGIN WORDPRESS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
###END WORDPRESS
```

Leaving the default WordPress instructions you should not have any problem, let me know

Comment: Benny, Thank you very much for your reply.
Unfortunately, It doesn't seem to change anything for me.
I am starting to wonder if there is something else causing the issue or preventing the redirect from working the way that it should.

Comment: @JoshRussell have you tried to disable the Redirection plugin temporarily to see if it works?

Comment: I just tried deactivating the Redirection plugin, clearing cache, and checking again - same result as before where http -> https works, but not stripping out www. Upon further inspection, when I disable Really Simple SSL, the http -> https redirection stops working, regardless of my htaccess file.

Comment: @JoshRussell the site is in production, in staging or in local development? Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Currently we are using Apache version 2.4.27 and the site is in production